# Could we have guided/automatic image resizing?

Tags: bug

When a user inserts an image using the button, though there's some maximum-width scaling from what I can tell, the image can still be pretty big. This leads to [some ugly stuff](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/revisions/28952/3), and even if a user is aware of it, unless they ask for help or know where to search, they won't know how to fix it without manually resizing images themselves.

So, can the site help out? Some options:

- The insert image UI could offer a size choice.
- When inserting images larger than a certain size, detect it and tell users how to reduce them.
- Default to a definitely safe choice (maybe the "m" size) and tell users how to *increase* it if the image is large. (Thanks, SAJ14SAJ - this is possibly the best since it means that inattentiveness still keeps the images small.)

This is related to an old [meta SO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101439/please-do-something-to-encourage-people-to-scale-down-their-giant-heavyweight-ph), but I want to let our site request it too - and note that even automatically limiting to 640x640 often leaves some larger-than-ideal images.

Comment: Adding a hint to the uploader UI may help. "We noticed that you are uploading a large image. Please consider reducing the display size of this image by..."

Comment: Oh, yes, yes, yes... and the default should guide people to the *small* image size most of the time, since large imagines in line just make reading and and scanning difficult.

Comment: A (fixed size) crop rectangle would really help.

Comment: Seems like cropping opens up a ball of worms and a bigger module. Just allowing for automatic sizes like small/medium/large would seem like a most useful start.

Comment: I marked this as a bug instead since answers can become unreadable as I show in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm particularly fond of the third suggestion:  make "m" the default size.

I'm not sure if this is unique to mobile Firefox, or to my Galaxy S4, but I invariably have to change the image size in posts to the "m" size in order to see all the text.

As you can see from the screenshot below, not only is the large image cropped to the right, but the text too!

[image: cropped text and image]

The above is [one of our highest voted answers](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/22409/1549) and some percentage of our users won't be able to read it without rotating their screen. For some posts even screen rotation doesn't help as can be seen in the [otherwise excellent post below](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/11872/1549).

[image: another cropped post]

Comment: It would really help if this could be combined with linking to full resolution, but I'm not getting my hopes up - you can't even do that with the toolbar, you have to type it manually...